# Number of subarrays which have elements less than k

Tags: arrays

I had the following question in an interview.
**Given an array you need to find all the subarrays which have elements less than given value k**
For e.g.

```
if k=4,
arr[]={4,8,2,4,6}
```

Now subarrays with values less than 4 are:

```
1.{4}
2.{2}
3.{2,4}
```

Notice how {4} was repeated but not considered twice.Now **the code should return the count of distinct subarrays.

In this case 3**.
Another example:

```
k=4
arr[]={2,3,8,2,4,6}
```

Distinct subarrays:

```
1.{2}
2.{3}
3.{2,3}
4.{4}
5.{2,4}
```

My approach was to find the subarrays less than given value k, which is O(n^2) and then insert it into something like unordered_set to remove duplicates.

Is there an efficient approach to this problem ?

Comment: My question is do you need the count of distinct subarrays or do you need to print as well all teh distinct subarrays because count of distinct subarrays can be done in O(n) I suppose.

Comment: @zenwraight count of distinct subarrays

Comment: If you're looking for a language-independent algorithm, you might want [cs.se] SE rather than here.

Comment: Wouldn't the second set of distinct subarrays be more like: {2};{2,3};{2,4};{3};{3,4};{4}?

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl it is a subarray, so it should be contiguous

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddling around with this for a few minutes I finally came up with a solution that meets verbatim what you are stating even though your results are different than mine. In your question you clearly state:

> Given an array, find all ***distinct subarrays*** which have elements ***less than*** a given value k.

You gave the following example which I use in my solution.

```
k=4
arr[]={2, 3, 8, 2, 4, 6}
```

You come to the conclusion that the result should be:

```
1.{2}
2.{3}
3.{2,3}
4.{4}
5.{2,4}
```

When in reality, if your requirements are truly met, you would only have three distinct arrays since the elements have to be less than the supplied value for `k` which in this example is `4`:

```
The values are: 2,3,8,2,4,6
Distinct Arrays Are: {2} {3} {2,3}
```

---

***SOLUTION (In C# 6.0)***

Feel free to test this on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) (will require tweaking to C# 4.5) or in Visual Studio (which currently handles C# 6.0). I'm not sure on how to translate this back to a mathematical formula for you if that is what you are needing in the end, but this solution works given the description of the desired result.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program {
    static int k = 4;
    static int[] vals = new int[]{ 2, 3, 8, 2, 4, 6 };
    static List<string> distinctVals = new List<string>();
    public static void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine($"The values are: {string.Join(",", vals)}");
        for (int x = 0; x < vals.Length; x++) {
        if (vals[x] < k)
                if (!distinctVals.Contains(vals[x].ToString()))
                    distinctVals.Add(vals[x].ToString());

            for (int y = 0; y < vals.Length; y++) {
                if (vals[y] < k) {
                    if (!distinctVals.Contains(vals[y].ToString()))
                        distinctVals.Add(vals[y].ToString());

                    if (vals[x] < k && vals[x] != vals[y])
                        if (!distinctVals.Contains($"{vals[x]},{vals[y]}"))
                            if (!distinctVals.Contains($"{vals[y]},{vals[x]}"))
                                distinctVals.Add($"{vals[x]},{vals[y]}");
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"There are {distinctVals.Count} distinct array elements.");
        Console.Write($"The distinct elements are: {{{string.Join("}; {", distinctVals)}}};");
    }
}
```